# Erro ao converter bitmap para pictureBox no C#?

Tags: c#, bitmap

Estou criando um caminho dentro do C# para poder sempre chamar imagens deste caminho,estou instanciando uma referência (`using namespace.Properties`) e através dela estou conseguindo chamar o `Resources` e usando o seguinte código :

```
var myIcon = (Bitmap)Resources.imagem;
```

Mas mesmo assim dentro do pictureBox ele não funciona,dá o seguinte erro :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'    teste   c:\users\Lucas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\teste\teste\Form1.cs   31  Active

**Tentativa de chamar a imagem :**

```
var myIcon = (Bitmap)Resources.imagem;
pictureBox1 = myIcon;
```

Eu quero que dentro desta `pictureBox` eu consiga chamar minha imagem que eu já estou chamando através do `Resources`,mas como posso arrumar este erro ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está no jeito que você está setando a picturebox

o correto é `pictureBox1.Image=myIcon`

Comment: Muito obrigado,funcionou agora perfeitamente :)